# threading a function

Tags: c++, boost, recursion, boost-thread

I have a recursive function that I want to thread, using either windows threading or boost threading. I have examples for how to do threading both ways, but I am not sure how to implement either, into my function. Below is the example of my boost threading.

```
struct  ThreadDemo {
    ThreadDemo( int secs ) : secs_(secs) { }

    void operator() (void) {
        boost::xtime xt;
        boost::xtime_get( &xt, boost::TIME_UTC );
        xt.sec += secs_;
        boost::thread::sleep( xt );
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(printing);
            cout << "Thread ended..." << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

I am just not 100% sure on how it works, but if you guys could help me to understand it better, I could hopefully implement into my function on my own.

Comment: It will greatly simplify your life if you convert your recursive function to one that uses a for loop.

Comment: This function is not recursive, what exactly are you trying to do? Also, you should always prefer high-level libraries (e.g. Boost.Thread) to low-level ones (e.g. pthreads, Windows threading API).

Comment: I freely admit that I just may be missing something, but where is the recursion here?

Comment: this is not meant to be the recursive function itself, im just trying to take this threading example, understand it, then take it and put it into my recursive function

Comment: @Bee: It'll be easier for us to point you towards a good solution if you post the code you actually want to get working.

Comment: Id rather not post my entire recursive function but i can explain in detial what it does: it recursively searches through directories searching for files with a specified extension and when it finds a file it then does a regex search in that file for a specified string, if the the function comes across another directory it then calls itself to search the contents of that directory. I am trying to add threading to the part that is doing the regex search, i hope this helps, if not, sorry.

Comment: What makes you think threading an IO-bound function like this will improve performance?

Comment: its not for performance reason, just for practice

Comment: If you want to learn MT and recursion, don't do fancy things with directory trees. Try recursive sorting, there the recursion pattern is much simpler and you don't risk obscure errors due to running out of available file handles.

Comment: Instead of recursion perhaps spin-off another thread? However I wouldn't see the need for threads to navigate or search directories and there are potential problems. If you want to play with threads for learning purposes write a program that solves the _N_ queens problem or integrals or something more applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you have looks like a functor - I think you are confusing that with a thread.
To make a thread in boost (or windows, or pthreads), all you need a function.
Here is a great reference (It is the one I used when first learning Boost threads) 
 http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401518